# How to get results from parallel sub-shells in Bash?

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, parallel-processing

I am running about 100 sub-shells and try to echo all results of them. Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function some_function(){} #spider
# ... ...
for i in {1..100}
do
  array[$i]=some_function $i &
done
echo ${array[@]}
```

I know these evaluations happen in sub-shells so nothing will I get.
But I cannot use

```
echo $(some_function $i) &
```

in the loop instead, because of **racing**, which made everything unreadable.

No idea why

```
(set -a; array[$i]=some_function $i; set +a)&
```

or

```
if true; then set -a; array[$i]=some_function $i; set +a; fi &
```

didn't work either.

*I did my best to avoid using any temp file or fifo or fd elsewhere.*

What is the proper way to do it?

Edit: I wonder if GNU-Parallel will work, though it is not in msys2.

Comment: GNU `parallel` is just another way to start background processes; it *itself* is another external process, so cannot set shell variables in the calling shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subshell cannot set the value of a variable (or array element) of its parent. Your only option is to write the output to a file.

```
for i in {1..100}; do
    some_function "$i" > "tmp_$i.txt" &
done

wait

for i in {1..100}; do
    array[i]=$(<"tmp_$i.txt")
done
```

(I thought there might be a way to use coprocesses, but it appears you cannot have more than one coprocess at a time.)

Comment: What about locking a file/fifo/fd and writing in turn, or passing some variable by reference?

Comment: Err...I wonder if using fifo will block the sub-shells, since elements of the array is evaluated one by one?

Comment: Any single file (regular file or fifo) will give you the same race condition.